# Notepad++ Autocomplete

Tags: notepad++, xml, autocomplete

I heard that Notepad++ has autocomplete but I can't find any documentation online to help with creating your own or how to do it.  If somebody could please point me in the right direction (or right out tell me, that's always nice), I would truly appreciate it!

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings->Preferences->Backup/Auto-Completion, then change the settings on the bottom half of the window.

Don't be underwhelmed though, it's not *that* impressive. :P

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Settings - Preferences - Backup/Auto-Completion` in order to enable it.

Find more information in the [Notepad++ Documentation here](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual//editing/auto-completion).

Autocompletion also relies on [user defined languages](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages).